# How does somebody have hundreds of badges and 1100 rep?

Tags: discussion

Sorry the numbers just seem, not possible ... for example:
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/1352/chefnelone?tab=badges

And how does somehow whose used drupal so much (3 years) not know what status messages on the reports page mean? .... it seems like a Bot.

Answer (score 3):

Badges are only marginally related to the reputation a user has; in fact, you can find users with less reputation than others, but more badges. (See [Citricguy](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/1747/citricguy) and [greg_1_anderson](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2618/greg-1-anderson), for example.)
There are badges given for the numbers of view a questions gets; a badge given for questions with no votes, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week; badges given for flagging or using the review queue.

Badges are a way to measure the participation of a user in a site; the reputation gives a measure of how much the user knows about a topic. They are two different measures that cannot be compared to each other.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bot and he gained the [**89 bronze badge**](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/badges/26/popular-question?userid=1352) only through [**Popular Question**](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/badges/26/popular-question) and yes it is possible to get that much if a question have **1000 views**!